# Using curl to post data to django 1.9 form

Tags: django, curl, django-forms

I am using django 1.9.

I have a form that uses the following fields:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    component = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(int(x.id), x.name) for x in Component.objects.all()])
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    notes = forms.CharField(max_length=2000, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}))
    file = forms.FileField()
```

I can use the form perfectly when I access it from a browser.

But when I try to use curl to fill the form, I keep getting error "**This field is required**"

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
<p><label for="id_title">Title:</label> <input id="id_title" maxlength="200" name="title" type="text" /></p>
<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
<p><label for="id_notes">Notes:</label> <textarea cols="40" id="id_notes" maxlength="2000" name="notes" rows="5">
</textarea></p>
<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
<p><label for="id_file">File:</label> <input id="id_file" name="file" type="file" /></p>
        <button type="submit"> upload file</button>
```

My `csrdmiddlewaretoken` is being accepted properly as I am able to see that in the response output.

Here are the different curl requests I tried:

```
`curl <url> \
-X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: text/html,application/json" \
-H "X-CSRFToken: <token grabbed from form page source>" \
-H "Cookie: csrftoken=<token grabbed from form page source>" \
 -d 'title=testCurl'`

`curl <url> \
-X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: text/html,application/json" \
-H "X-CSRFToken: <token grabbed from form page source>" \
-H "Cookie: csrftoken=<token grabbed from form page source>" \
 -F 'title=testCurl'`

`curl <url> \
-X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: text/html,application/json" \
-H "X-CSRFToken: <token grabbed from form page source>" \
-H "Cookie: csrftoken=<token grabbed from form page source>" \
 -d '{"title":"testCurl"}'`
```

Once this works, I need to find a way to pass a file in the file field.

Can anyone help me out with this?

----- Edits:
Based on suggestion from @ohrstrom:

I see the following when I do 'copy as curl' from chrome developer tools.

```
curl 'http://localhost:8000/releases/binary_upload' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=84666B9EE0BB747F04AC3179FEB78F65; csrftoken=E50JjoNz1qigYUehGdxPjnsscCNaFslu' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8000' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryn3n6mrAf19RXCh3A' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8000/releases/binary_upload' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryn3n6mrAf19RXCh3A\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"\r\n\r\nE50JjoNz1qigYUehGdxPjnsscCNaFslu\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryn3n6mrAf19RXCh3A\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="component"\r\n\r\n13\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryn3n6mrAf19RXCh3A\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="title"\r\n\r\ntest1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryn3n6mrAf19RXCh3A\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="notes"\r\n\r\ntest123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryn3n6mrAf19RXCh3A\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Topology_Components.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryn3n6mrAf19RXCh3A--\r\n' --compressed
```

But when I execute the same command from terminal, it says 'The submitted file is empty'

========Final Edit========
Found a solution. Adding it to answers below.

If you need more implementation details, you can find it at https://github.com/kiran-vemuri/DevServe

Comment: You are not sending the form data, hence the errors. See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) for how to send form data using curl.

Comment: Please show the view. Are you processing JSON there? If not, why are you sending JSON?

Comment: To easily get the curl command: submit the form via browser (chrome) with developer tools open. Then you can right-click the request and choose 'copy as curl'.

Comment: @ohrstrom: Thanks for the comment. I see the curl I pasted in the question when I do 'copy as curl'. But when I execute the same command from terminal, it says 'The submitted file is empty'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly sending a `POST` request to a web form. I am currently implementing `django-restframework`.

With `viewsets` for all type of HTTP requests, I added some extra file processing and now I can use the following REST call to send data using curl.

```
`
curl -H "Content-Disposition: attachment;" \
-X POST \
-F "name=test_file" \ 
-F "component_id=14" \
-F "notes=Hello World how are you.." \
-F "file=@<path-to-file>" http://localhost:8000/rest/binaries/
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Form fields in Django are required by default:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#required

You are only sending the 'title' field in your data, and that is the only field not giving an error.

Either send all the form fields in the data that you are sending, or make the fields required=False.

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    component = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=[(int(x.id), x.name) for x in Component.objects.all()])
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    notes = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=2000, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}))
    file = forms.FileField(required=False)
```

Comment: Initially I started sending all the fields. After seeing the error on all the fields, I started sending only title field to check if I can find a way to resolve the error. And if you notice the output I pasted above, you can see the error on the title field as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used to pass only Data and its values so i used this much only:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-d '{"name":"testcurl","ph":"123456789"}'
```